# Merging data into long format based on time and ID in R

Tags: r, dplyr, merge

I am trying to merge two dataframe into a long format dataframe based on two variables "time" and "ID"

```
df1<-data.frame(id=c(1,2,3), time=c(1,1,1), var=(1,0,1), var1=(1,0,1)
df2<-data.frame(id=c(1,2,3), time=c(2,2,2), var=(0,1,0))
```

So that the end result of the merged dataframe will look like this

| time | ID | var | var1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |  |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |  |
| 2 | 3 | 0 |  |

Please let me know how I could do it in r, much appreciated. Thanks!

I tried using the left_join command,

```
x<-left_join(df1,df2,by=c("ID","time"))
```

but it gives me an error message as follows:

Error in `left_join()`:
! Join columns in `y` must be present in the data.
✖ Problem with `time`.

I tried using rbind:

```
x<- rbind(df1,df2)
```

but I get the following error message below:
Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) :
numbers of columns of arguments do not match

Comment: I think you are looking for `rbind(df1, df2)`.